# Increase touch target size jQuery ui slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make the jQuery UI Slider more user friendly on mobile devices.
This is why I want to increase the size of the touch target area to move the slider. I don´t want to increase the actual size of the button. I just want to increase the box around the button. So even clumsy users or users with big thumbs can easily controle the slider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play around with CSS to increase padding around the button.

```
.ui-slider-handle{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

However, increasing the padding around button without making the button size bigger will be little tricky.

```
.ui-slider-handle{
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: -11px;
  border: none !importnat;
  background: 0 !important;
}
.ui-state-default, 
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, 
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default,
.ui-slider-handle:hover{
  border: none !important;
}
.ui-slider-handle:after{
  content: "";
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Please see the example below.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ohsik/k57o3em4/2/

You probably have to play around with CSS to make it look the way you want it to be.